# MySQL : How do I select the next rows from ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this table :

```
ID      CONTENT
1       test 1
2       test 2
3       test 3
4       test 4
5       test 5
6       test 6
7       test 7
8       test 8
9       test 9
10      test 10
```

How do I select the next 5 rows starting from `ID 5` ?

So i should get rows with ID 6,7,8,9,10

Comment: `select * from table order by id limit 5,5` ?

Comment: Did you at least get to `WHERE ID>5` and `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. All your answers are wrong except the one from @ÁlvaroG.Vicario `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID > 5 LIMIT 5`

Comment: You are talking about essentially creating Paging.   You need to LIMIT and then use NEXT.... so that way it will filter by sets of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from your_table 
where id > 5 
order by id asc limit 5
```